# i have to convert the csv file date format to excel date format

Tags: excel, csv, date-format

how can i convert the .csv file date format to excel date format time.

csv date format and time    to  excel date format and time
Nov 10 2014  9:06:29:846AM  >>  11/10/2014 9:06AM

Comment: Is that a typo or is the decimal portion of your time using a colon where there would normally be a full stop (aka *period*)? You have `9:06:29:846AM`, not `9:06:29.846AM`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either modify the format that the data comes to you at the export application or you can transform the date/times after you import that column in as text. There is no magical transformation that Excel uses that can adjust the data as provided. If you were able to get the data with the decimal portions of the seconds in the time prefaced with a decimal point as is the norm and the year was prefaced with a comma and a space instead of just a space then you would have a fighting chance. As it is, I know of no internal machinations that Excel can use to transform that data on-the-fly. Here is a more manual approach.

1. Import your data to a new worksheet
2. Insert a new column beside your date/times and format the column using the *Custom Number Format* of Type: **mm/dd/yyyy h:mm AM/PM**
3. Put this formula into the second row of this new *helper* column `IFERROR(DATEVALUE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A6," 2014", ", 2014"),12)),0)+IFERROR(TIMEVALUE(REPLACE(RIGHT(REPT(" ",14)&A6,14),9,4," ")),0)` and fill down as necessary to collect all values from the imported text-based dat/times you imported.
4. Examine the new column to see if there are any errors. When you are happy with the results, Copy and Paste Special, Values back into the original column.
5. [Optional] Delete or clear the *helper* column.